# Insert only specific columns with DBT

Tags: sql, dbt

As of now, I have an INSERT INTO clause, that works like this:

```
insert into final_table (name, age, created_at)
select *
from person_table
```

The final_table has 4 columns: ID (incremental/serial), name, age and created_at. The person_table has only name, age, and created_at.

When I translate it to the dbt logic, it looks like this:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental'
    )
}}

with person_table as (
  select *
  from person_table
)

select
   name,
   age,
   created_at
from person_table

{% if is_incremental() %}
    AND created_at > (select max(created_at) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

However, dbt keeps compiling as an INSERT CLAUSE containing the ID (that it is auto-generated). Does anyone know how to insert only the specific columns that I want?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Most data warehouses don't support auto-incrementing pks.

If you run your code with `--full-refresh`, the result should be a table with only three columns: `name, age, created_at`

Comment: I'm using Snowflake. Yes, but I need the ID column so the issue is that I can't pass it, because it is an auto-generated column. This seems like a pretty basic feature, that I don't find anyone talking about in dbt!

Comment: If `id` doesn't exist in the source, just create a model downstream from this model that uses `row_number()` to add it. You could also modify your incremental model to compute the ID if you want to do that in this model. Would it be helpful if I typed a solution with that? (there may be unintended side effects)

Comment: Oh my god, yes! Hahah I'm new to dbt, and this part is preventing to move forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [row_number](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) to fake an auto-incrementing key in Snowflake.

In a model materialized as a table, that would be as simple as:

```sql
select
   name,
   age,
   created_at,
   row_number() over (order by created_at asc) as id
from person_table
```

But since this is an incremental model, your inner query will be filtered before `row_number()` is computed, so we need to add on the maximum value of `id` in the table if the model is being run in incremental mode:

```sql
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental'
    )
}}

{% if is_incremental() %}
    {% set max_id = "(select max(id) from " ~ this ~ ")" %}
{% else %}
    {% set max_id = 0 %}
{% endif %}

with person_table as (
  select *
  from {{ ref('person') }}
)

select
   name,
   age,
   created_at,
   {{ max_id }} + row_number() over (order by created_at asc) as id
from person_table
where 1=1
{% if is_incremental() %}
    AND created_at > (select max(created_at) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

Note that, if you `--full-refresh` this model, and records were deleted from `person_table`, then any records created after the deleted records will have their IDs changed. No real way around that, unfortunately! If you need an immutable ID, I would suggest hashing some combination of name, age, and created_at using `md5` or [`dbt_utils.surrogate_key`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#surrogate_key-source). Of course, those hashed ID's would not be monotonically increasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. It is a shame that we have to work with such a turnaround on dbt. Seems like such a basic feature...

Comment: By the way, do you know if is it possible to have two models with the same name in dbt? Because I have a table that is going to consume data from two sources

Comment: model names have to be globally unique but you can use `alias` to get them to materialize to tables in your database with the same name. https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-aliases